# IntelliJ IDEA: How to disable temporary run/debug configurations creation or preserve a permanent configuration?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I am using Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 and whenever I run a gradle task from gradle side panel (for example clean or build) a new temporary run/debug configuration is created. I want to disable this behaviour.

The documentation only says how to create/save configurations, or at least I couldn't find anything about how to disable their automatic creation.

The only thing I found was "temporary configuration limit". After setting it to 0, they are no longer created, but my original run configuration is still being set to blank and I have to select my original one from the dropdown again. I must admit that it becomes a bit annoying.

Is there any way to pin down a configuration so that it never changes until I change it myself by selecting another one from the dropdown menu?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: There is no such way.

Comment: Really? That's a shame :(